Spring Boot Error: Consider defining a bean of type
Spring Boot 3.0.0
Trying to run my application, but I'm getting the error:
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.pcoshealthtracker.controller.RegistrationController required a bean of type 'com.example.pcoshealthtracker.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.pcoshealthtracker.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
my main app class:
package com.example.pcoshealthtracker;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.pcoshealthtracker")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.pcoshealthtracker.repository")
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

UserRepository
package com.example.pcoshealthtracker.repository;

import com.example.pcoshealthtracker.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
    boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}

RegistrationController
package com.example.pcoshealthtracker.controller;

import com.example.pcoshealthtracker.entity.User;
import com.example.pcoshealthtracker.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RegistrationController {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public RegistrationController(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * Endpoint to register a new user.
     */
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();

        // Check if email or username already exists
        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
            response.put("status", "error");
            response.put("message", "Email is already registered.");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(user.getUsername())) {
            response.put("status", "error");
            response.put("message", "Username is already taken.");
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }

        try {
            // Hash the user's password before saving
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userRepository.save(user);

            response.put("status", "success");
            response.put("redirectUrl", "/login.html");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.put("status", "error");
            response.put("message", "Registration failed: " + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Endpoint to check the availability of a username or email.
     */
    @PostMapping("/check-availability")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Boolean>> checkAvailability(@RequestBody Map<String, String> payload) {
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();

        String email = payload.get("email");
        String username = payload.get("username");

        if (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) {
            response.put("available", !userRepository.existsByEmail(email));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        }

        if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
            response.put("available", !userRepository.existsByUsername(username));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        }

        response.put("available", false); // Invalid request
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
    }
}

User Entity
package com.example.pcoshealthtracker.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true) 
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "date_created", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now();

    // Getters and Setters
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() { 
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) { 
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(LocalDateTime dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.pcoshealthtracker</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcos_health_tracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>pcos_health_tracker</name>
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web Starter for building web applications -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot JPA Starter for database interactions with JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- MySQL Connector for MySQL database connection -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot DevTools for development utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter JDBC for database connections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Test for testing utilities -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JUnit Jupiter for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin for building and running the application -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

application.properties
# Database Configuration for pcos_health_tracker
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pcos_health_tracker
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=563324
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true


# Logging level
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG

server.port=8080


I've tried ComponentScan and that didn't work. Any ideas how to fix this?
I've tried
package com.example.pcoshealthtracker; // Note the package

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.pcoshealthtracker") // Scanning the root package
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

but get the same error

There must be something in there that you aren't showing, your App class should only need an @SpringBootApplication and the other annotations shouldn't be necessary at all. I would disable bean-overriding as that would introduce more problems then it solves, next to that there probably is somewhere an error related to your UserRepository in your logging about one of the methods you have added.

Please try to add @EntityScan("com.example.pcoshealthtracker.entity") below @EnableJpaRepositories. BR
